# How do I plot an entire data array, not just a singe value from it?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot 200 frequency vs. dB data points on one line graph. My code first has a lot of stuff to get rid of headers in my data (18 lines), and then an attempt to save the columns (frequency and dB) as arrays and plot them, but python is outputting a blank graph with no error.

Very new to python, so not sure what to do here! Thanks in advance!

Here is my current code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def skip_first(seq,n):
    for i, item in enumerate(seq):
        if i>=n:
            yield item

frequency=[]
dB=[]
with open('2.csv','r') as s11_load:
    csvreader = csv.reader(s11_load)
    for row in skip_first(csvreader, 18):
       frequency = row[0]
       dB = row[1]
       print(frequency)
       #print(dB)

plt.plot(frequency,dB,linestyle='-',color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample csv that could allow us to test your code?

Comment: any reason for not using pandas dataframe.  skiprows is just a param there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas at all, so that's why I didn't use it initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always updating frequency and dB lists instead of appending to them

try replacing:

```
frequency = row[0]
dB = row[1]
```

by:

```
frequency.append(row[0])
dB.append(row[1])
```

that should do the trick. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pandas package, it could simplify your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv("path to file", skiprows = 18) #skip headers
df.plot(x = , y = ) #Plots graph using matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

You give `frequency` and `dB` a new value (a float) in each loop. So, when you try to plot your graph, they're just single values.

You already defined them as lists, you just have to [append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) the values to these lists:

```
frequency=[]
dB=[]
with open('2.csv','r') as s11_load:
    csvreader = csv.reader(s11_load)
    for row in skip_first(csvreader, 18):
       frequency.append(row[0])
       dB.append(row[1])
```